# How to change the speed of setInterval in real time

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to change the speed of setInterval in real time e.g:

```
if (score < 10)
    repeater = setInterval(function() {
        spawnEnemy();
    }, 1000);
if (score => 10)
    repeater = setInterval(function() {
        spawnEnemy();
    }, 500);
```

I know this method doesn't work, but is there a way that I can achieve this some other way?

Comment: DRY: Note you're changing only one parameter here, so what you really need is `repeater = setInterval(() => { ... }, delayForScore(score))`, or maybe with a further refactoring, trigger every 100ms and check if it's time or not, if this time fluctuates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way would be to just use `setTimeout` rather than `setInterval`.  Do the check every time so you can keep your speed logic in a separate function.

```js
var game_over = false;
var score = 0;

function getSpeedFromScore(score) {
  if (score > 20) {
    game_over = true;
  }

  if (score < 10) {
    return 1000;
  } else {
    return 500;
  }
}

function spawnEnemyThenWait() {
  if (!game_over) {
    spawnEnemy();

    var speed = getSpeedFromScore(score);
    setTimeout(spawnEnemyThenWait, speed);
  }
}

function spawnEnemy() {
  document.getElementById("output").textContent = "Enemey spawned: score " + score;
  score++;
}

spawnEnemyThenWait();
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bq926xz6/

Answer (score 5):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/vdt1hdms/)***

There is no way to change the interval speed itself once running. The only way to do it is to have a variable for the speed, and then clear the interval and start a new one with the new speed.

```
var speed = 500;
var changeSpeed = speed;
repeater = setInterval(repeaterFn, speed);
function repeaterFn(){
    spawnEnemy();
    if( changeSpeed != speed ){
     clearInterval(repeater);
     speed = changeSpeed;
     repeater = setInterval(repeaterFn, speed);
    }
}
function changeRepeater(){
 changeSpeed = 700;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a nice suggestion, better than mine. But I would create a function, that recreates the interval instead of setting a variable.. maybe.

Comment: Good point. Except that you could ... _theoretically_ ... log the current time (`(new Date()).getTime()`) on each call of `repeaterFn` and then... wow won't think that till the end.. it would either give a huge mess or be miles of source code. Forget about that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `clearInterval`:

```
if (score < 10) {
  clearInterval(repeater);
  repeater = setInterval(spawnEnemy, 1000);
}
if (score => 10) {
  clearInterval(repeater);
  repeater = setInterval(spawnEnemy, 500);
}
```

But it depends on the context. If this snippet is executed more often, than it *has to* be, you will need some kind of mechanism to prevent it from resetting your interval all the time.

But there is (as I wrote in the comment to the question) no way to use `clearInterval` and *change* the interval itself. At least not without replacing it by a new interval as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a game loop and track the spawn state in an enemy class:

```js
// press f12 so see console
function Enemy() {
  this.spawned = false;
  this.spawnOn = 20;

  this.tick = function() {
    this.spawnOn = this.spawnOn - 1;
    if (this.spawnOn == 0) {
      this.spawned = true;
    }
  }

  this.goBackToYourCage = function() {
    this.spawnOn = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1;
    this.spawned = false;
  }
}

var enemy = new Enemy();

window.setInterval(function() {
  enemy.tick();
  
  if (enemy.spawned) {
    console.log('spawned');
    enemy.goBackToYourCage();
    console.log('Next spawin in :' + enemy.spawnOn);
  }
}, 100);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/martijn/qxt2fe8y/2/

Comment: This is my favorite one! No fiddling with changing the actual tick speed, so it separates the game timer from the enemy's behavior. OOP is OP :)