# setInterval incrementally faster

Tags: javascript, time, setinterval

Given a setInterval, can its timer keep getting quicker?
Such as that the code to be ran starts at 2 seconds, then 1.9s, 1.8s, 1.7s, etc...? (at this point I'm not worried about reaching zero or negative.)

I currently have:

```
let speed = 2000;

let timer = setInterval(function() {
 display();
 faster();
 console.log(speed)
}, speed);

function faster() {
 speed -= 100;
}

function display(){
 // displays another square on canvas
}
```

I ask if it is possible because the console.log shows that the speed does indeed decrease, but the display function is not being called at faster intervals; it is always being called every 2 seconds. Therefor the speed of the setInterval is not getting faster....

Comment: Have you tried using `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` and call `timer` from inside the timer callback method?

Comment: No, you can not change the interval timer of a running interval. You’d have to clear the current one and start a new one - or use setTimeout to begin with, if you want to execute it only once for any of those given time intervals.

Comment: Already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28287914/how-to-change-the-speed-of-setinterval-in-real-time

Answer (score 2):

No. The `setInterval()` rate is fixed at the value of the second argument when the timer is started.

You can use `setTimeout()` instead, reestablishing the timer upon each invocation of the callback:

```
var rate = 100;
setTimeout(function callback() {
  // do something
  setTimeout(callback, rate - 10);
});
```